# Nested While Loop Not Working Properly

Tags: php, while-loop

I started working on php lately and i don't know why while loop is not working properly, the problem is value of $sexy['post_id'] doesn't get updated. I have 2 rows in my table

```
$getpostId = "SELECT post_id FROM likersTable WHERE executed='0'";
$postIdDetails = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$getpostId)
                or die('Some error in post id');

$getAllUserId = "SELECT * FROM likersTable";
$allUserIdDetails = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$getAllUserId)
                    or die('Some error in all user id');

while($sexy = mysqli_fetch_array($postIdDetails)){
    while($shitty = mysqli_fetch_array($allUserIdDetails)){
        echo 'User Id: '.$shitty['user_id'].'<br />';
        echo 'Post Id: '.$sexy['post_id'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the field `executed` in the database (as you mentioned in the `WHERE` clause `WHERE executed='0'"`)? If it's a numeric type such as `INT`, `TINYINT`, `FLOAT`, `DECIMAL` etc then you must drop the single quotes around `0`.

Comment: it is an INT, removing quotes will make it work?

Comment: Yes of course, if it's `INT`, you must drop the single quotes.

Comment: i did that, but it still works the same way

Comment: If you put these two statement after the first `while` loop means this `while($sexy = mysqli_fetch_array($postIdDetails)){}` then it should work but it might not be the perfect and recommended solution. `$getAllUserId = "SELECT * FROM likersTable";
$allUserIdDetails = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$getAllUserId)
                    or die('Some error in all user id');` Just give it a try.

Comment: it worked now, thanks, but what is the actual problem? why isn't it working as i wrote?

Comment: You had been receiving this error because the array as specified with the inner loop means this one `$allUserIdDetails` is exhausted very first time the loop is iterated and hence, the array would not be available to be iterated over when you enter the loop next time.

Comment: Since my prime subject is Java, I can not make more defined statement about this. I'm less concerned with PHP. Really very sorry.

Comment: anyways, thanks a ton, if you can post the solution in Answer, i won't mind marking it as correct :)

Comment: It's so very nice but I think it's sufficient to leave it just as a comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: Additionally, use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of using `mysqli_fetch_array()` because `mysqli_fetch_array()` has both indices numeric and associative hence, you can use both indices such as `$shitty['user_id']` and `$shitty[0]` which takes much more time to execute than `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` which has only associative indices hence, you can not use something like this `$shitty[0]` with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_fetch_assoc, instead of mysqli_fetch_array

You probably also want to be doing mysqli_data_seek($allUserIdDetails, 0) between the first and second while.

Comment: not working mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc !== mysqli_fetch_assoc - note the extra i

Answer (score 0):

I would try this as the first part of debugging.

```
$sexy = mysqli_fetch_array($postIdDetails);
$shitty = mysqli_fetch_array($allUserIdDetails);
print_r($sexy);
echo "<br><br>";
print_r($shitty);
```

That outputs whats in the sexy and shitty array respectively.

Also, `executed='0'` must be `executed=0` if the fieled `executed` is an `INT`.

+1 for using mysqli. I am still a mysql shit.